# Should I update Ubuntu on WSL?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

[image: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows]

The output of `lsb_release -a` is the following.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Should I upgrade? Do I risk to break it?

Answer (score 10):

Yes its possible and there are two options:

1. Use `lxrun`to install and uninstall `bash`:

   ```
   lxrun /uninstall
   lxrun /install
   ```
2. Upgrade with `do-release-upgrade`:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

Information:

- The second method might work according to the link given below, but that article is `2016` so this method might work.
- Here is clip from Microsoft

  > Note: WSL will install Ubuntu version 16.04 (Xenial) instead of Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty) 
  >       in an upcoming release. This change will apply to Insiders installing new instances (lxrun.exe /install or first run of bash.exe). 
  >       Existing instances with Trusty will not be upgraded automatically. 
  >       Users can upgrade their Trusty image to Xenial using the do-release-upgrade command.

Source:

https://www.howtogeek.com/278152/how-to-update-the-windows-bash-shell/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/release_notes#build-14936

Comment: I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS release. I can edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` by changing `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` and then `do-release-upgrade` duly informs me that Artful 17.10 can be installed. I haven't see this documented by Microsoft though. Has anyone tried it?

Comment: For `do-release-upgrade` you might need to set `RELEASE_UPGRADER_NO_SCREEN=1`: `sudo -S env RELEASE_UPGRADER_NO_SCREEN=1 do-release-upgrade` (source: http://wsl-guide.org/en/latest/update.html)

Comment: @amaslenn: Here's a link that explains *why* `RELEASE_UPGRADE_NO_SCREEN` is needed: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/927

Answer (score 0):

You should backup and reinstall WSL. This time you should install a newer version from the Windows Store choosing your favorite distro.

Comment: WSL and distro are entirely separate. WSL provides a lightweight VM with additional capabilities, such as reasonably fast host filesystem access. The networking is based on the same infrastructure as HyperV. It does require a Microsoft patched kernel, that has all this support compiled in. Since 2020 or so, WSL has been decoupled from Windows, and is feature-upgraded through MS Store at a much better pace than Windows 11. So no, reinstalling a distro is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -S apt-mark hold procps strace sudo
sudo -S env RELEASE_UPGRADER_NO_SCREEN=1 do-release-upgrade
```

These should update the Ubuntu on Windows to the latest version.

Comment: What's the `-S` flag for?

Comment: Why hold procps, strace and sudo? This is [against Debian recommendations](https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#disable-apt-pinning) (4.11, 4.13).